# Can you help me installing MinGW?

Tags: installation, mingw

When I try to install MinGW I get this error message:

```
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** C:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\mingw-get-0.dll: DLL load failed; cannot run setup hooks
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** setup: unable to continue
```

I have no idea what should I do, I just wanted to start learning C... can you help solve this problem?

Comment: What a shame no one has a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by deleting the MinGW folder from my C: drive completely and rerunning the installer executable.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all files in `C:\MinGW\var\cache\mingw-get\packages` and install WinGW again and it worked.